# Como converter uma cadeia de caracteres de apenas numerais em data?

Tags: vb.net

Como faço pra converter uma cadeia de caracteres de apenas numerais em data? Por exemplo, tenho uma variável com o seguinte valor "31012000" que seria referente a data 31/01/2000, porém não estou conseguindo converter esses número para data e poder trabalhar com ele como data, não como string.

Já tentei o seguinte e não deu certo:

```
Dim stringData as string = "31012000"

Dim dataConvertida as Date = stringData.format("dd/MM/yyyy)
```

Ou

```
Dim dataConvertida as Date = Date.Parse(stringData)
```

Ou

```
Dim dataConvertida as Date = Convert.Date(stringData)
```

Nenhuma dessas alternativas funcionaram.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui, quebrei um pouco a cabeça e o que fiz foi inserir manualmente "/" para que assim a string pudesse ser atribuída a variável data sem precisar converter:

```
    Dim stringData As String = "31012000"
    Dim novaString As String = ""
    For Each c As String In stringData
       novaString += c
       If novaString.Length = 2 Or novaString.Length = 5 Then
       novaString += "/"
       End If
    Next
    Dim novaData as Date = novaString
```